# Form action starting with question mark

Tags: html, forms, url

Today I had a conflict with a team because he states that this is an invalid URL:

```
<form action="?foo=bar" method="get">
```

He states: because the browser get in troubles trying to resolving the correct document where should be redirect, and the data can be lost across between browser and server.

I have mad simple HTML with a form and submitted to W3C validator and I do not see any problem. However, I do not find any "official" documentation where say that this practice is invalid or not.

I have these documents that looks good, but do not confirm a valid or invalid URL:

- http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt
- https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is valid, but useless. RFC 3986, designated as Internet-standard 66, is authoritative in matters of URL syntax, and it contains nothing that would make the relative URL `?foo=bar` invalid. However, when it appears as the value of an `action` attribute in an HTML form, is its discarded; the page behaves just as `action=""` had been specified (or the `action` attribute omitted).

The reason is that the [mutate action](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#submit-mutate-action) in HTML form submission *replaces* the query part. It is defined so that the query part is *set* to a query constructed from the form data; at the extreme, it is just `?`, but normally it consists of a question mark followed by name=value pairs separated by ampersands. In any case, `?foo=bar` is lost.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML is valid however it's not the right way to send parameters using a form. If your form was sending things via POST then this would be less of an issue but a GET should use it's own parameters and the form should just post to itself.

e.g:

```
<form action="file.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
    ...
</form>
```

Full example (confirmed working):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: By the way, don't rely on HTML validators to tell you if you are using code correctly, all it can tell you is that the structure is/isn't valid. That doesn't mean it's necessarily best-practice.

If you are unsure of the quality of your code, Stack Exchange has a site specifically for code-review, I highly recommend it. You can see some information about it here:

http://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: It does not send parameters at all.

Comment: It would work if it was a POST. I think that is where the OP's confusion is coming from.